# After a Google Sheets update IMPORTRANGE errors everywhere

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I noticed that on Monday (2/13/17) Google made an update to Google Sheets, the filters are now a different color (green). After this update, the IMPORTRANGE function has just been volatile. It doesn't work. I remember this used to be a problem two years ago, I thought they fixed this.

Where do I complain to Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Complain to Google

There are several ways to complain to Google.

### From Google Sheets

1. Open a spreadsheet
2. Click on Help > Report a problem
3. Fill up the feedback form and submit it

### From the Google Docs Editors Help

1. Go to https://support.google.com/docs#topic=
2. Click on Help Forum

Or just go directly to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs

### If you are G Suite user

Go to https://connect.googleforwork.com

or

Ask your domain administrator to submit a support ticket